# Mysql Connector connect() issues

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a small C++ project and need to access a mySQL DB from it, so i have setup mySQL Connector for C++.
This is done on OS X 10.10, and i got no problems with the compilation/linking.

I have written a class for all the mysql stuff, and in the constructor i want to setup the connection to the db. However, this seems to be kinda hard.

Here is the relevant part from the class:

```
class mysql{

public:

  mysql(std::string server, std::string user, std::string password);

private:

  sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;

  std::string last_error = "";

};
```

And here the implementation:

```
mysql::mysql(std::string server, std::string user, std::string password){

  driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();

  try{

    con = driver->connect(server, user, password);

    last_error = "";

  }
  catch(sql::SQLException &e){

    last_error = e.what();

  }

}
```

However, when i create an object of that class like this:

```
mysql db("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "secretsecret");
```

I then have this in my last_error string:

> Unknown MySQL server host '???' (0)

The "host" sometimes differs even tho i dont change it in code. This seems like internally a different memory location is read out as it should be.
But even if i pass the connect() variables directly when i call it, i get this error. Same when saving those three variables internally in the mysql class and use those to call connect().

Anyone has an idea what could cause this? I have a similar implementation in a different project where this does work fine so im kinda confused :/

Comment: That looks like memory corruption where the "server" is being passed.

Comment: Ye thats what i thought, but i have no idea why it gets corrupted..

Comment: You could create a minimal test case, reproduce the problem, then step into debugger and break the code at **MySQL_Driver::connect**. That is the place where you want to print **hostName**.

Comment: I hope you are using latest libraries of mysql.

Comment: im using the same library in a different project with nearly the same code and its working fine..

Comment: You can also try to generate log file by this [method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-debug-tracing.html), which works only if you fortunate enough to have debug versions of connector and driver.

Comment: Why aren't you passing the strings by reference? Better still, `const` reference? Don't pass objects around entire in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140024/osx-yosemite-mysql-5-6-netbeans-c-connector-hostname-string-issues?rq=1) that matches to your circumstances (The C++ connector works on linux and fails on OSX).

With using mysql logging/tracing or running it in debugger, you may be able to gather more information to report to mysql developers. You may have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of googeling i found this the most useful link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251290/weird-behaviour-of-mysql-connector-c-in-osx

Following the hints there, i recompiled the myscl c connector and then the mysql c++ connector (version 1.1.6 cause 1.1.7 caused a json error while compiling).

I also saw in the cmake logs of the c++ connector that Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ was used to compile the library.

So i used that one too for my compilation. It could be that this would work, tho im also including wxwisgeds in my project resulting in this error:

```
/usr/local/include/wx-3.0/wx/strvararg.h:30:18: fatal error: 'tr1/type_traits' file not found
    #include <tr1/type_traits>
```

I found some hints for that one but they all just produced a massiv amount of new errors, so i stopped digging deeper here.

My best options would be to create two seperate programs, on to communicate with mysql and one to provide the gui and let them both communicate with each other either via sockets or files providing a very inefficient access to a mysql db.

Good luck to anyone who runs into the same thing..